Message Passing between Background and Popup [Chromium: 127.0.6533.119 - ]
I have a working message passing extension as follows:
//manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "B2P",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Check B2P",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker" : "background.js"
    }
}

// popup.html
<html style="min-width:200px;">
<head>
</head>
  <body>
    Say Hi
  <script src="./popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

// popup.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.msg === "B2P") {
            //  To do something
            console.log(request.data.subject);
            console.log(request.data.content);
            sendResponse({login:'initiated'});
        }
    }
)

// background.js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    msg: "B2P", 
    data: {
        subject: "Background to popup",
        content: "Failed!"
    }
}, function(response) {console.log(response);});

Suddenly after an update to Chromium: 127.0.6533.119 onwards on ubuntu, this message passing has stopped working... And it flash error Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. in background.js.
Am I doing anything wrong?

The entire workflow is wrong, because the popup only runs when it's shown, so the correct solution is to reverse the flow: the popup should use chrome.runtime.sendMessage and the background script should listen to messages and respond using sendResponse as shown in the documentation.

Got it. Should I withdraw the question to maintain consistency of this channel? @woxxom

You can add an answer showing your fix and explaining why it works.
